# Symfony2, Doctrine2, query builder with strange result values?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to select my articles from my Article object and join comments as count for number of comments for this article. So I have this build:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('a, COUNT(comments) AS comments_count')
                ->from('AcmeBlogBundle:Article', 'a')
                ->leftJoin('a.comments', 'comments')
                ->groupBy('a.id')
                ->orderBy('a.id', 'DESC');
$articles = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But I'll try to load my article list in my TWIG template, I'll get this error:

```
Key "title" for array with keys "0, comments_count" does not exist in AcmeBlogBundle:Admin:index.html.twig at line 13
```

My <kbd>index.html.twig</kbd>:

```
  {% for article in articles %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ article.title }}</td>
    <td><a href="{{ path('default_blog_show', {'slug' : article.slug}) }}">Visit</a> | <a href="{{ path('admin_blog_edit', {'article_id' : article.id}) }}">Edit</a> | <a href="{{ path('admin_blog_delete', {'article_id' : article.id}) }}" onclick="return confirm('Any question...');">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

But, query is OK, I checked it in my profiler:

```
SELECT 
  a0_.id AS id0, 
  a0_.title AS title1, 
  a0_.slug AS slug2, 
  a0_.content AS content3, 
  COUNT(c1_.id) AS sclr4 
FROM 
  articles a0_ 
  LEFT JOIN comments c1_ ON a0_.id = c1_.article_id 
GROUP BY 
  a0_.id 
ORDER BY 
  a0_.id DESC
```

If I try to dump `$articles` by using `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($articles);` property, I'll get this result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(30) "Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Article"
    ["comments_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Any idea where's the problem with this query results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because doctrine returns an array of values.

Use this in your template and it should see the title:

```
<td>{{ attribute(article, 0).title }}</td>
```

EDIT:

try this in your twig template:

```
  {% for item in articles %}
  {% set article = item[0] %}
  {% set comment_count = item['comments_count'] %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ article.title }}</td>
    <td><a href="{{ path('default_blog_show', {'slug' : article.slug}) }}">Visit</a> | <a href="{{ path('admin_blog_edit', {'article_id' : article.id}) }}">Edit</a> | <a href="{{ path('admin_blog_delete', {'article_id' : article.id}) }}" onclick="return confirm('Any question...');">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes it works, but why it have these not pretty values? Is there any way, to make this query with better results without any this "magic"? (like article.title, article.comments_count)

Comment: On your edit - Key "1" in object (with ArrayAccess) of type "Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Article" does not exist in AcmeBlogBundle:Admin:index.html.twig at line 13

Comment: Not if you don't have separate article and comment entityes with one to many relation betwen them. Then you could use count($article->getComments()) because getComments() sould return a collection of comment entityes.

Comment: edited the edit... was using 1 instead of comments_count as key.

Comment: Yes I'm using One to Many relation between Article and Comment Entities. So, $article->getComments -> how can I implement this in every article?

Comment: use "length" in twig loop... like {{ article.getComments|length }}. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html